# How to get Spinner value?

Tags: android, spinner

In Android, I am trying to get the selected Spinner value with a listener.

What is the best way to get the spinner's value?

Answer (score 640, accepted):

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.your_spinner);
String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: "Value" is pretty ambiguous here. This retrieves the current spinner item title (as in, the String that is displayed to the user), but not its value if you mapped an int array onto the spinner for example.

Comment: @Doge to get value of selected item like integer value for example
we should make int[] valuesArray and file it in onCreate function maybe from arrays.xml
so we can use valuesArray[(int)mySpinner.getSelectedItemId()]
to get integer value

Answer (score 138):

The Spinner should fire an "OnItemSelected" event when something is selected:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks -- that worked, though I needed to add the void return type to the methods.

Comment: Is there really no way to achieve this without relying on the item's position?

Comment: Not a very useful solution if you want to read the spinner value without relying on a selection event.

Comment: Don't onItemSelected and onNothingSelected need @Override above them?

Comment: @Patrick The annotation Override is never required it just tells the compiler "Can you check if this override is done correctly?"

Comment: @SiXoS Interesting, I never knew that. But, it looks like the best practice is to use Override notation:  stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why

Comment: What about getting the default selected item when no change performed on it? @dodo's one is the most proper.

Answer (score 56):

Say this is your xml with spinner entries (ie. titles) and values:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="size_entries">
        <item>Small</item>
        <item>Medium</item>
        <item>Large</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="size_values">
        <item>12</item>
        <item>16</item>
        <item>20</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and this is your spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/size_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/size_entries" />
```

Then in your code to get the entries:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.size_spinner);
String size = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); // Small, Medium, Large
```

and to get the values:

```
int spinner_pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
String[] size_values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.size_values);
int size = Integer.valueOf(size_values[spinner_pos]); // 12, 16, 20
```

Comment: Thx, this should be in the official ANDR doc on spinner, they only showed getting value via Listener.

Comment: this exactly what i looking FOR

Comment: Perfect solution! `android:entries` made my day.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you can register a listener via `setOnItemSelectedListener()`, as is demonstrated [here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Selection/Spinner/).

Comment: Thanks -- this worked too, and (I think) it makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 15):

```
View view =(View) getActivity().findViewById(controlId);
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String valToSet = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 12):

If you already know the item is a `String`, I prefer:

```
String itemText = (String) mySpinner.getSelectedItem();
```

Calling `toString()` on an `Object` that you know is a `String` seems like a more roundabout path than just casting the `Object` to `String`.

Answer (score 5):

add setOnItemSelectedListener to spinner reference  and get the data like that`

```
 mSizeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            selectedSize=adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```