# Want to display spinner selected values on textview when button is clicked

Tags: android

I have taken 3 edittext in my form and three spinner. I can easily get the data from edit text and display it on Textview, but the problem is how to get the data from spinner and display all the edit text and spinnner values in textview.
I am creating a form in which when the button is clicked all the data from edittext text and spinner is displayed on Textview

Comment: What you have implemented? post it.

Comment: try with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947933/how-to-get-spinner-value

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

```
String textValue= yourSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_btn);
btn.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListener {

public void onClick(View v)
 {
   String spinnerStr = yourSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
   String editTextStr = yourEditText.getText().toString();
   yourTextView.setText(spinnerStr + editTextStr);
 }
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v){ 


    String item= spinner .getSelectedItem().toString();
    textView .setText(item);

}
});
```