# How to get value in second spinner and third spinner after selected first spinner and calculate

Tags: android, spinner

How to get value in second spinner and third spinner after selected first spinner and calculate [to create a simple converter]

here the code, there is no error in my code but this coding not run perfectly, please help me guys..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private Spinner firstSpinner, secondSpinner, thirdSpinner;
private Button convert;
EditText input, output;
Double awal, numtemp;
String num, hasil;


ArrayList<String> ChooseType = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> ChooseSuhu = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> ChooseBerat = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> ChoosePanjang = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> ChooseData = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firstSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ChooseType);

    secondSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ChooseType1);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    thirdSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ChooseType2);
    output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.konBut);


    fillarray();

    firstSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ChooseType));
    firstSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pos == 1) {
                secondSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ChooseSuhu));
                thirdSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ChooseSuhu));
            }
            /*else if(pos == 2){
                secondSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ChooseBerat));
                thirdSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ChooseBerat));
            }
            else if(pos == 3){
                secondSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ChoosePanjang));
                thirdSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ChoosePanjang));
            }
            else if(pos == 4){
                secondSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ChooseData));
                thirdSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ChooseData));
            }*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    convert.setOnClickListener(new convert());


}


public void onClickListener(){
    secondSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg2 == 0){
                num = input.getText().toString();
                awal = Double.parseDouble(num);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    thirdSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            numtemp = awal;
            hasil = numtemp.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
}


private class convert implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        output.setText(hasil);
    }

}

private void fillarray() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ChooseType.add("Choose");
    ChooseType.add("Suhu");
    ChooseType.add("Berat");
    ChooseType.add("Panjang");
    ChooseType.add("Data");


    ChooseSuhu.add("celcius");
    ChooseSuhu.add("reamur");
    ChooseSuhu.add("fahrenheit");
    ChooseSuhu.add("kelvin");


    ChooseBerat.add("pon");
    ChooseBerat.add("ton");
    ChooseBerat.add("miligram");
    ChooseBerat.add("gram");
    ChooseBerat.add("kilogram");
    ChooseBerat.add("oz");


    ChoosePanjang.add("centimeter");
    ChoosePanjang.add("feet");
    ChoosePanjang.add("inche");
    ChoosePanjang.add("kilometer");
    ChoosePanjang.add("meter");
    ChoosePanjang.add("mile");
    ChoosePanjang.add("centimeter");


    ChooseData.add("bit");
    ChooseData.add("byte");
    ChooseData.add("kilobit");
    ChooseData.add("kilobyte");
    ChooseData.add("megabit");
    ChooseData.add("megabyte");
    ChooseData.add("gigabit");
    ChooseData.add("gigabyte");
    ChooseData.add("terabit");
    ChooseData.add("terabyte");
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Spinner value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947933/how-to-get-spinner-value)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
OtherSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```