# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ClassCastException: When adding an onItemSelected listener

Tags: java, android, listener, spinner

I am creating a spinner based on a webservice call where the items are built in a loop.

Before initiating the loop I wanted to add a default "Select Item" item but when I do I get a fatal exception:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: com.anyscreeninc.posterviewer.Events cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence

```
if (status.contentEquals("complete")){
    final Spinner event_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.events);

    EventAdapter eAdapter = new EventAdapter(posterSessionSetup.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, eventList);

    event_spinner.setAdapter(eAdapter);

//When I add this listener I get the error....
//============================================

    event_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter, View v, int i, long lng) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence)  event_spinner.getSelectedItem(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
    }
    });
}
```

This is my modified EventAdapter

```
public class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Events> {
    private Activity context;
    ArrayList<Events> data = null;

    public EventAdapter(Activity context, int resource,
                          ArrayList<Events> data) {
        super(context, resource, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }


}
```

I am building this stuff based on several differnt tutorial.

I tried to change the (CharSequence) in the Listener to (ArrayList) but AndroidStudio tells me "can't resolve method"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this that should work.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), event_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: What if I want the value of the selected item? Like in HTML you can do <option value="">.. Can I do that with a spinner and this listener?

Comment: @silversunhunter why you do not check docs first or google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947933/how-to-get-spinner-value

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Why do you think I did not? I searched but was not understanding what was wrong. Sorry, but I am brand new to Java.

Comment: @silversunhunter because link I gave shows up as 1st when you search for "android spinner current value". Java got nothing with this.