# How to retrieve text file name being displayed in textview

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` that displays different text files depending on the user selection from a `Spinner`. How can I get the name of the text file that is being displayed? The files are in the raw folder.

Comment: How do you display your text? If you read the text from the file, then you obviously have access to the file. Hence you can read the filename.

Comment: yea i have the first file name but i need to get other names of files being selected

Comment: Care to show us some of your code? Also check `getSelectedItem()`

Comment: the code i have is for reading the file, havent come up with any for getting file name. just help me out, u have a textview, how do u get the name of the text file being displayed. thanx

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/7486969/4848308

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to obtain the file from raw after being selected in a spinner

```
Spinner mySpinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.your_spinner);
String rawTextName = = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(rawTextName ,
            "raw", getPackageName()));
```

If you need to read the content this should work

```
TextView textView =(TextView ) findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
textView.setText = readTextFile(ins);
```

...

```
public String readTextFile(InputStream inputStream) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return outputStream.toString();
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: thanx but all i want is if u have a TextView, how do u get the name of the text file being displayed, forget the spinner.

Comment: did you meant text inside TextView widget?