# How to get/pass the selected value from spinner to onclick

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner included on my form. Now I need to pass the selected value and include it on my form request. Populating the Spinner is already working, I just need to get the selected value. I am fairly new to Android, so I will greatly appreciate any help or tips you can offer.

**Here's the Spinner value:**

```
//this method will execute when we pick an item from the spinner
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //Setting the values to textviews for a selected item
    tvID.setText(getName(position));
}
```

This is my submit button function:

```
btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String firstname = etFname.getText().toString();
                final String lastname = etLname.getText().toString();
                final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
                final String phone = etContact.getText().toString();
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                final String department = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
//GET the value of spinner and include it here
```

I will need the spinner value so I can include it on my request:

```
RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(firstname, lastname, email, phone, username, password, responseListener);
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
queue.add(registerRequest);
```

EDIT: I tried the solutions below but I'm getting this error:
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30598142/1391818

if you are mapping some strings to values

Comment: error and your question are not at all related :)... post `responseListener` class and for `RegisterRequest` what last parameter (return type)  needs.

Comment: @skadoosh yes thank you I already fixed my Request class. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the selected value in a global string and then pass it to your request.

Something like this

```
String sel_spinner;

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Setting the values to textviews for a selected item
        tvID.setText(getName(position));

         sel_spinner=getName(position);
    }
```

Then use this string here

```
btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String firstname = etFname.getText().toString();
                final String lastname = etLname.getText().toString();
                final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
                final String phone = etContact.getText().toString();
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                final String department = sel_spinner;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Other answers also work, it's just that I need to get the ID value, not the Department Name that is shown in the spinner. So I used this solution instead and converted the String to int. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

This may helps you

Answer (score 0):

To get the spinner value Use the following code

```
String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you above code is working as you mentioned and this method is calling

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //Setting the values to textviews for a selected item
    tvID.setText(getName(position));
}
```

Then you can also get value like this.

```
btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String firstname = etFname.getText().toString();
                final String lastname = etLname.getText().toString();
                final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
                final String phone = etContact.getText().toString();
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                final String department =  tvID.getText().toString();

          }            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Question1 :- How to get selected value of spinner

Answer :- For getting selected item of spinner you must use getSelectedItem() method on your spinner item you can do these by :-

```
public  String getName(int position) 
{  
          spinnerreferece.setSelection(position);
            String selVal = (String) spinnerreference.getSelectedItem();
  return selVal
}
```

Question 2:- How to pass value of selected item :
Answer 2:- I am assuming u want to pass value to other activity :-

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id) {
    String selValue = (String) getName(position);
tvID.setText(selValue);   
//it se
 cho=Integer.parseInt(selValue);
    changescreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (cho)
            {
                case 1:
                    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Secondactivity.class);
                    Log.d("xml", String.valueOf(i));
i.putExtra("key",selValue);           
             startActivity(i);

                    break;

                    }
                    }
```

By doing these two thing you can achieve your desired task .I hope it will help you .