# I get error in spinner selected value

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm trying to make an app to send messages with default or user predefined messages and phone numbers I will put here my code

```
 private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS = 0;
String phoneNo, message;
List<String> pn, txt;
Spinner sp1, sp2;
Button b, b1, b2, b3, b4;
EditText et, et1;

ArrayAdapter<String> adp1, adp2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setupSpinners();

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adp1.add(et.getText().toString());
            et.setText(null);
        }

    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adp2.add(et1.getText().toString());
            et1.setText(null);
        }

    });
}

public void setupSpinners() {

    sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    pn = new ArrayList<String>();
    txt = new ArrayList<String>();
    txt.add("Sorry Boss I'cant go today i'm sick");
    pn.add("123456789");

    adp1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, pn);
    adp2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, txt);

    sp1.setAdapter(adp1);
    sp1.setSelection((pn.size() - 1));
    sp2.setAdapter(adp2);
    sp2.setSelection((txt.size() - 1));

    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            sp1.setSelection(arg2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }


    });
    sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            sp2.setSelection(arg2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    sendSMSMessage();
                }

                protected void sendSMSMessage() {
                    phoneNo =  sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    message =  sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                        } else {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
                    switch (requestCode) {
                        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
                            if (grantResults.length > 0
                                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The part where it gives the error is the (this,

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
 Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
} else {
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
```

I need help to know how to select the spinner selected value to send trough text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Spinner value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947933/how-to-get-spinner-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one line code for get selected value in spinner.

```
String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

In your code

```
protected void sendSMSMessage() {
                    phoneNo =  sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    message =  sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: now i'm getting an error in the

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,


(this,  is the error part

In the gradle build it says
error: incompatible types: <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Activity

error: incompatible types: <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context

Comment: can you post a question so we can understand clearly..??

Comment: You need to add run time permission. with proper code

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: if you don't understand then see my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139754/android-6-0-marshmallow-cannot-write-to-sd-card/37358852#37358852

Comment: If i do another question could you help me with the code? I've seen your answer its useful but I still cant apply it to my code witouth giving me errors

Comment: what is the problem in it ? i Don't understand

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: make your targetsdkversion to 22 in your gradle.

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: you can  remove your permission code. no need for runtime permission. after set to 22

Answer (score 0):

`pn` and `txt` variables are `List`s, there is no such method like `getText()` on `List`s.

Comment: I'm only starting here sorry if I don't know some basics

Comment: No problem, I was just saying :-)